# "Does not implement IControllerFactory.CreateController" in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, castle-windsor

When compiling this code:

```
public class WindsorControllerFactory : IControllerFactory
{
    private readonly WindsorContainer _container;

    public WindsorControllerFactory(WindsorContainer container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    public IController CreateController(RequestContext requestContext,
                                        string controllerName)
    {
        return (IController)_container.Resolve(controllerName);
    }

    public void ReleaseController(IController controller)
    {
        _container.Release(controller);
    }
}
```

I am getting this error:

> 'WindsorControllerFactory' does not
>   implement interface member
>   'System.Web.Mvc.IControllerFactory.CreateController(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext,
>   string)'

Well, it obviously implements this member. Has anyone encountered this problem?

I reproduced this on the RTM, opened a [ticket with Microsoft](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/550123/does-not-implement-icontrollerfactory-createcontroller).

Comment: Try right-clicking the IControllerFactory afteer ":" and say implement interface and the missed will come up

Comment: @Oskar - There is no missed method, that's the problem. If I comment out the method CreateController, and do "implement method" using Resharper, the code still does not compile.

Comment: Try implementing explicitly then?

Comment: @Oskar - nice idea, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Also, I tried to extend DefaultControllerFactory instead of implementing IControllerFactory, but that didn't work.

Comment: Just a guess, is "RequestContext" in your method really "System.Web.Routing.RequestContext" try exchanging that

Comment: @Oskar - no, unfortunately it's nothing that trivial.

I am now contemplating a workaround. I am able to extend DefaultControllerFactory, but I can't override the method. Instead, I can add a new method, catch the call by reflection / debugging API somewhere, and redirect it to my method instead of the one in Default. Tricky as hell, but I don't see what else I can do.

Comment: I wonder what would be easier - doing that, or downgrading to Visual Studio 2010 beta 2, which did work for me with similar code. Grrr.

Comment: +1 for posting the Connect link.

Comment: @John - Microsoft closed this as "by design". I simply do not understand.

Answer (score 3):

Error went away after I added reference to System.Web.Routing 4.0.0.0. Before this it was indirectly referenced to 3.5.0.0 version (through System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)

Thus i have the following references:
System.Web.Mvc 2.0.0.0 (v2.0.50727)
System.Web.Routing 4.0.0.0 (v4.0.30128)

Comment: I will give your suggestion a try.

Comment: Helped me! This was the case in a .NET 4.0 solution with custom controllers defined (Through IController) and with MVC 2.0 referenced.

Answer (score 0):

you might have two conflicting versions of System.Web.routing or something like that.

Comment: did you install multiple Betas or RCs? do you have some suspicious stuff in the bin folder?  

did you try compiling it with csc.exe?
btw - look at the output window of VS to see its generated csc.exe call?

Comment: I had beta 2 previously, then fully uninstalled it then and installed RC. I'll try see what csc.exe says.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a `RequestContext` class in the `System.ServiceModel.Channels` namespace; included in the System.ServiceModel.dll assembly.

Hover over the RequestContext argument type of your your method and check that it pointing to the correct one.

More information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.requestcontext.aspx)

Comment: I wrote the explicit class name, it didn't help :(

Comment: And did you write System.Web.Routing.RequestContext or System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestContext?  You should have the first.

Comment: I wrote System.Web.Routing.RequestContext and it didn't work. It's just an insolvable bug in Visual Studio I guess. I'll upgrade to the RTM and see if it solves it.

Answer (score 0):

Include a reference to System.Web (v4.0.30319).